# overlay issue with menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having the issue with the overlay of a menu, when I open the menu the content in the background is still visible, i have tried playing with the z-index but it doesn't help.

The paragraph is seen in light gray when you open the menu .

```js
$("#menu").click(function() {
  $(".nav").toggleClass('is-open');
  $(".overlay").toggleClass('is-visible');
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
html {
  color: #222;
  font-family: Avenir, sans-serif;
}
a {
  color: #111;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: lighter;
  opacity: .7;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.nav {
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}
.nav li {
  transition-delay: 0.15s;
  transform: translate(30px, 0);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}
.nav.is-open li {
  transform: translate(0px, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}
.nav.is-open li:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.nav.is-open li:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.15s;
}
.nav.is-open li:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.nav.is-open li:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: 0.25s;
}
.nav.is-open li:nth-child(5) {
  transition-delay: .3s;
}
.nav.is-open li a {
  color: #fff;
}
#menu {
  float: right;
  width: 25px;
  height: 15px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#menu span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #222;
  border-radius: 2px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .15s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .15s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .15s ease-in-out;
  transition: .15s ease-in-out;
}
#menu span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}
#menu span:nth-child(2),
#menu span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 9px;
}
#menu span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 18px;
}
#menu.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 9px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}
#menu.open span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#menu.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
#menu.open span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 9px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}
#menu.open span {
  background: #fff;
}
header {
  float: right;
  padding: 50px;
}
header {
  position: relative;
}
.overlay {
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: -4;
  transition: background .5s ease-in-out;
}
.overlay.is-visible {
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <a id="menu" href="#">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </a>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<div class="overlay">Hello,<br>this is the para that is still visible when you open the menu</div>
```

Comment: It's because it is the same element with different properties applied. You would either need to wrap the paragrph in an element where you can alter it's z-index (or opacity etc). Or you would actually need the open menu to be a different item that 'sits on top' of the paragraph. The other 'trick' would be to make the open menu background #222 or make your body text colour #000.

Comment: because your header element did not cover your .overlay div

Comment: @lharby the other trick will not work as in my page i have different colored elements and the menu and the paragraph sits in the same view

Comment: @laravel14 can you please suggest a fix if possible ?

Comment: Wrap the text that you want hidden in an element, a paragraph for example.  Then you can say `.overlay.is-visible p {z-index -1;}, .overlay p {z-index:0;}` this is quite hacky though. You are entering z-index hell.

Comment: Just add this  `color:transparent` rule in `.overlay.is-visible`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have different colors per paragraph, I suggest you to use a pseudo-element inside your `.overlay` element. You'll be able to colorize it, and it will hide your content:

```
.overlay {
  position: relative;
  ...
}
.overlay.is-visible:after {
  content: '';
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

**Whole snippet:**

```js
$("#menu").click(function() {
  $(".nav").toggleClass('is-open');
  $(".overlay").toggleClass('is-visible');
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
html {
  color: #222;
  font-family: Avenir, sans-serif;
}
a {
  color: #111;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: lighter;
  opacity: .7;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.nav {
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}
.nav li {
  transition-delay: 0.15s;
  transform: translate(30px, 0);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}
.nav.is-open li {
  transform: translate(0px, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}
.nav.is-open li:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.nav.is-open li:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.15s;
}
.nav.is-open li:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.nav.is-open li:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: 0.25s;
}
.nav.is-open li:nth-child(5) {
  transition-delay: .3s;
}
.nav.is-open li a {
  color: #fff;
}
#menu {
  float: right;
  width: 25px;
  height: 15px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#menu span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #222;
  border-radius: 2px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .15s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .15s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .15s ease-in-out;
  transition: .15s ease-in-out;
}
#menu span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}
#menu span:nth-child(2),
#menu span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 9px;
}
#menu span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 18px;
}
#menu.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 9px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}
#menu.open span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#menu.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
#menu.open span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 9px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}
#menu.open span {
  background: #fff;
}
header {
  float: right;
  padding: 50px;
}
header {
  position: relative;
}
.overlay {
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: -4;
  transition: background .5s ease-in-out;
}
.overlay.is-visible:after {
  content: '';
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <a id="menu" href="#">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </a>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<div class="overlay">Hello,<br>this is the para that is still visible when you open the menu</div>
```

Comment: This is the best answer. It works by making content "" through css but along three additional fields width, height, top needs to be set. It does not work if any of these three fields are modified. Any reason.

Comment: With this code, you're adding a "real" overlay, via the pseudo-element. It needs to cover the whole page, this is why I use absolute positioning and width/height 100%. (Note: have you noticed the selector has changed? `.overlay.is-visible:after`)

Answer (score 1):

Below code is working for your.

```js
$("#menu").click(function () {
            $(".nav").toggleClass('is-open');
            $(".overlay").toggleClass('is-visible');
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
 });
```

```css
 * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        li {
            list-style: none;
        }
        
        html {
            color: #222;
            font-family: Avenir, sans-serif;
        }
        
        a {
            color: #111;
            display: inline-block;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 10px 0;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: lighter;
            opacity: .7;
            transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;

        }
        
        a:hover {
            opacity: 1;
            
        }
        
        .nav {
            text-align: right;
            float: right;
        }
        
        .nav li {
            transition-delay: 0.15s;
            transform: translate(30px, 0);
            opacity: 0;
            transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
        }
        
        .nav.is-open li {
            transform: translate(0px, 0);
            opacity: 1;
        }
        
        .nav.is-open li:nth-child(1) {
            transition-delay: 0.1s;
        }
        
        .nav.is-open li:nth-child(2) {
            transition-delay: 0.15s;
        }
        
        .nav.is-open li:nth-child(3) {
            transition-delay: 0.2s;
        }
        
        .nav.is-open li:nth-child(4) {
            transition-delay: 0.25s;
        }
        
        .nav.is-open li:nth-child(5) {
            transition-delay: .3s;
        }
        
        .nav.is-open li a {
            color: #fff;
        }
        
        #menu {
            float: right;
            width: 25px;
            height: 15px;
            position: relative;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
            -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
            transition: .3s ease-in-out;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        
        #menu span {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            height: 2px;
            width: 100%;
            background: #222;
            border-radius: 2px;
            opacity: 1;
            left: 0;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
            -webkit-transition: .15s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: .15s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: .15s ease-in-out;
            transition: .15s ease-in-out;
        }
        
        #menu span:nth-child(1) {
            top: 0px;
        }
        
        #menu span:nth-child(2),
        #menu span:nth-child(3) {
            top: 9px;
        }
        
        #menu span:nth-child(4) {
            top: 18px;
        }
        
        #menu.open span:nth-child(1) {
            top: 9px;
            width: 0%;
            left: 50%;
        }
        
        #menu.open span:nth-child(2) {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
        }
        
        #menu.open span:nth-child(3) {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
        }
        
        #menu.open span:nth-child(4) {
            top: 9px;
            width: 0%;
            left: 50%;
        }
        
        #menu.open span {
            background: #fff;
        
        }
        header {
            float: right;
            padding: 50px;
        }
        
        header {
            position: relative;
            z-index:2
        }
        
        .overlay {
            background: transparent;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
   z-index: -4;
            transition: background .5s ease-in-out;
            position:absolute;
            top:0px;     
         }
         .overlay-2 {
            width: 100%;              
         }
        .overlay.is-visible {
            background: #000;              
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
            display:block;                
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
   
        <a id="menu" href="#">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </a>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
 

 
    <div class="overlay-2">Hello, <br> this is the para that is still visible when you open the menu</div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
```

Or

You want single div with `.overlay` then write below line in css.

```
.overlay.is-visible {
   color:transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the js code:

```
$("#menu").click(function() {
  $(".nav").toggleClass('is-open');
  $(".overlay").toggleClass('is-visible');
  $(".overlay p").toggle('display');

  $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

And in the html add p tag to content :

```
 <div class="overlay"><p>Hello, <br> this is the para that is still visible when you open the menu</p></div>
```